# Pendências de tradução na página de perfil

Tags: suporte, status-pronto, tradução

Novamente há na nossa interface vários textos não traduzidos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seguem, daqueles que encontrei, os links no Traducir.win:

1. <strike>`Edit profile and settings`</strike> [status-pronto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-pronto)

   - Link no Traducir.win: https://pt.traducir.win/string/10567
   - Chave: 69266bcdb5b1ae711ad949b1f8f058fd
2. <strike>`Favorites`</strike> [status-pronto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-pronto)

   - Link no Traducir.win: https://pt.traducir.win/string/10028
   - Chave: d78986947356ddd37b43d57df289dee9
3. <strike>`Bounties`</strike> [status-pronto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-pronto)

   - Link no Traducir.win: https://pt.traducir.win/string/3013
   - Chave: 4d62090a68fbefcd4c72632b8aea71b9
4. <strike>`All actions`</strike> [status-pronto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-pronto)

   - Link no Traducir.win: https://pt.traducir.win/string/10558
   - Chave: 2701bbdc7ebed3bba6e85534149c85b1
5. <strike>`Responses`</strike> [status-pronto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-pronto)

   - Link no Traducir.win: https://pt.traducir.win/string/10584
   - Chave: b9ee5f76a4d9b6b73e94eb7a131aa91e
6. <strike>`All`</strike> [status-pronto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-pronto)

   - Link no Traducir.win: https://pt.traducir.win/string/10590
   - Chave: d7353ef768d02818bcb80104f8978258|refersTo=activities
7. <strike>`Accepts`</strike> [status-pronto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-pronto)

   - Link no Traducir.win: https://pt.traducir.win/string/10600
   - Chave: ef155fc683df99981cab20b2afe99613
8. <strike>`Reviews`</strike> [status-pronto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-pronto)

   - Link no Traducir.win: https://pt.traducir.win/string/10559
   - Chave: 34e80a799d144cfe4af46815e103f017

Este foio traduzido como "Revisões", mas dada a imagem, acredito que seria melhor a tradução para "Análises" (se é que é esse mesmo o registro no traducir.win)

9. <strike>`Suggestions`</strike> [status-pronto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-pronto)

   - Link no Traducir.win: https://pt.traducir.win/string/10560
   - Chave: 41ecca7200a4431cf9b855a62e6ab666

Comment: Aprovadas todas as suas sugestões no traducir.win :)

Comment: No meu perfil ainda aparecem esses textos em inglês. Demora um tempo pra atualizar ou é [cache](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)?

Comment: @hkotsubo Então, quando aprovadas no Traducir.win elas são enviadas ao transifex; lá não sei como funciona o fluxo, se já entra em produção ou se há builds em períodos específicos.

Comment: "Meta user" e "Network profile" também faltam.